# Very simple C++ lexical analysis in Java

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I need to analyze some C++ source files in order to generate some very basic information. The thing that I am trying to do goes like this:

1. Assume that we have the C++ grammar and the C++ source file to be analyzed
2. The analyzer will read the source file like a lexical analyzer, it'll identify the keywords etc. as defined by the C++ grammar.
3. After reading each line, the analyzer will output the following information: Line#: lexical information. For example, consider this:

   ```
   int main(int x, int y)
   {
      return x+y;
   }
   ```

The program will output:

```
    Line 1: function: main, params: x, y
    Line 2: paren "{"
    Line 3: keyword: "return"
```

or something similar.

Can somebody please tell me how to do this? I have looked at Antlr and TXL but I'm guessing that there should be a simpler way. I'd like to write a Java program that'll do this work.
The first thing that I would like to do is to get the function definitions in a file, with their corresponding line numbers. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Anton

Comment: Best bet is to get Clang to do the parsing and you just analyse the AST, I think.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a place to find people to write your code. Is there a more specific question you can ask? Or perhaps some code to show where you got before you got stuck?

Comment: "Assume that we have the C++ grammar" How do you mean this? You have regexes for matching it? If you already have the proper regular expressions, you've won half the battle already.

Comment: "Very simple C++ lexical analysis"?  Ha Ha, very funny.  There's no such thing as *simple* C++ lexical analysis, so *very simple* C++ lexical analysis is quite out of the question.  C++ does not permit separation of lexing from semantic analysis.

Comment: @Jasper: When did I ask to write code?

Comment: @IamChuckB: There are C++ grammars available for antlr, lex and txl. I was hoping someone has used the tools or something like that. That would be like, winning the full battle.

Comment: @Anton You didn't. My problem was that you didn't say what you did want either. At least, I didn't get it out of your question (it may indeed be me.)

Comment: @Jasper: No problem, I'm new to stackoverflow...next time I will be more careful.

Comment: I think this link has what I was looking for:http://www.txl.ca/examples/Applications/AnnotateCpp/AnnotateCpp.tar.gz
Anyways, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Anton, you cannot even do a "simple" lexical analysis for C++ without parsing and resolving the types. Grammar is ambiguous, there is no way to distinguish, say, identifiers from types in a lexing stage. Most of the current production C++ parsers are doing really dirty tricks with patching the lexer using the current semantic context, and some are using lexerless GLR parsing instead, deferring the semantic decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet, as of today, is probably [CLang](http://clang.llvm.org/).

While CLang is known for being a C/C++/Objective-C/Objective-C++ frontend on top of LLVM, it has been designed as a set of libraries *specifically* so that individual components could be re-used outside the compiler itself.

Of interest, `libclang` is a C library that wraps the core preprocessing and semantic analysis to provide a "parsed-tree" in C, because C is the lingua franca. `libclang` notably serves as a basis for the Python bindings, so if you really want it in Java you should be able to use the JNI (if I remember correctly the terms) to interface with it. Also, the `libclang` interface is extremely stable (unlike the internal compiler representations) as it is *meant* to be used by external users.

The Python bindings have already been used to create `clang_complete`, a vim plugin for auto-completion. You can read this [blog article](http://zwiener.org/vimautocomplete.html) about it for example (there is a nifty video showing it in action).

*Insider note: the Python bindings are currently being significantly improved by Gregory Szorc under the guidance of Tobias Grosser, you can [see Gregory's announcement here](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Python-bindings-overhaul-td3694785.html).*

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ya, CLang seems like something that can be worth checking out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the output that you've suggested, you are not doing lexical analysis; you're doing at least a bit of parsing, since you have to understand that what you're looking it is, say, a function declaration versus an object initialization.  Lexical analysis would give you back something like

```
int
main
(
int
x
,
int
y
)
{
return
x
+
y
;
}
```

Whereas you'd like to understand that those first tokens actually define a function.

Unfortunately, parsing C++ is notoriously difficult and most parser generators have to be very specially calibrated to produce a working C++ parser.  I would suggest looking into an existing C++ parser framework, perhaps something like [Elsa](http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/sources/elsa/index.html).  This will give you the information you need in a format that you should be able to use.  Another option would be to hook into the C++ compiler directly and process the underlying AST, which handles all the parsing and line number information for you.  The [Treehydra](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Treehydra) tool might be useful here, though you'd be writing JavaScript code rather than Java.

Hope this helps!